# NSTableView toolTipFor cell - How to display tooltips for cells?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, tableview, tooltip

I have a view-based TableView, the delegate Outlet of the TableView is set to my ViewController. My ViewController implements the NSTableViewDelegate protocol and has the method toopTipFor cell method implemented.
However, If I hover the mouse over any cell, no tooltip is displayed and the method is not even called.

I have created a small sample XCode project, you can download it here:
https://ranger81.de/_sub/temp/ToolTipTest.zip

Here is a code snippet:

[image: code snippet]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView(_:toolTipFor:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:)` is only valid for `NSCell`-based table views. Implement the tooltip in the cell view or its subviews.